# Django - How do you get the corresponding model object in a for loop in html?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I am trying to create a simple django website where any user can rate and create posts. As displayed in this django tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/), you can display all the model objects in html using a for loop. In my case, each object is going to be displayed with a Like and a Dislike button, so people can rate the post. My problem is: How do I know which object belongs to which like/dislike button so that the corresponding model field can be changed for that particular object? Thank You for answers!

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    post_text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published")
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_text
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AllPosts</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if post_list %}
<ul>
    {% for post in post_list %}
    <li>{{post.post_text}}</li>
    <p>This post has {{post.likes}} likes and {{post.dislikes}} dislikes.</p>
    <br>Leave a <button type="button" method="LIKE">Like</button> or a <button type="button" method="DISLIKE">Dislike</button>!</p>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
<h2>If you want to create a post yourself, <a href="{% url 'create' %}">click here.</a></h2>
{% else %}
<h1>There are no posts yet...</h1>
{% endif %}


</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.

def index(request):

    post_list = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    template = loader.get_template('post/index.html')
    context = {'post_list': post_list, }
    #if request.method == "LIKE":
    #    post = Post.objects.get(id=) How do I find out the id?
     #   return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
    #else:
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def create(request):
    template = 'post/create.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = Post()
        post.post_text = request.POST.get("post_text")
        post.pub_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()

        return render(request, template)

    else:

        return render(request, template)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the buttons to work, they need to be inside a form element and be of `type="submit"` otherwise they won't do anything when clicked. To identify which button was clicked, you can then replace the `method` attributes with `name="like"` and `name="dislike"`. The buttons can then be referenced to the related post by setting their value to the post ID.

Below is an example of the code that should do this. I've clipped out some of the unrelated parts of the code. (*Note: I haven't tested this, so it may not work perfectly*)

`index.html` UL element:

```
<ul>
    {% for post in post_list %}
    <li>
        <span>{{post.post_text}}</span><br>
        <p>This post has {{post.likes}} likes and {{post.dislikes}} dislikes.</p>
        <form method="post">
            <p>
                Leave a <button type="submit" name="like" value="{{post.id}}">Like</button>
                or a <button type="submit" name="dislike" value="{{post.id}}">Dislike</button>!
            </p>
        </form>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

`views.py` index:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        like = request.POST.get('like')
        dislike = request.POST.get('dislike')
        if like:
            # Handle liked post
            # `like` is equal to the post ID
        else if dislike:
            # Handle disliked post
            # `dislike` is equal to the post ID
        else:
            # No action requested
    else:
        post_list = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
        template = loader.get_template('post/index.html')
        context = {'post_list': post_list, }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

I hope this helps :)